# Error when using Peity.js and metricsgraphics.js together

Tags: jquery, metricsgraphicsjs

I tried to draw bar chart using Peity.js, and it worked. I tried to draw another graph using metricsgraphics.js, and it worked. However, when I combine them , it gives me error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DEFAULTS' of undefined  (metricsgraphics.min.js:2)
```

Please check the image .
[image: Error in the console]

Can you help me to solve this problem, please?

This is the metricsgraphics code for my chart.. When I add it, I get the error.

```
grapghData=
[
      {  "date": "2014-04-23",  "value": 115877608   },
       {  "date": "2014-04-24", "value": 132088857  },
        { "date": "2014-04-25","value": 112071353  },
        { "date": "2014-04-26", "value": 81790062 },
        { "date": "2014-04-27", "value": 105003761 },
        { "date": "2014-04-28",  "value": 100457727 },
        { "date": "2014-04-29", "value": 118253926 },
        { "date": "2014-04-30", "value": 67956992  }
    ];

grapghData = MG.convert.date(grapghData, 'date');
    MG.data_graphic({
        title: "Line Chart",
        description: "This is a simple line chart. You can remove the area portion by adding area: false to the arguments list.",
        data: grapghData,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        right: 40,
        target: document.getElementById('fake_users1'),
        x_accessor: 'date',
        y_accessor: 'value'
    });
```